# App won't show up in physical device when debugging in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, adt, eclipse-adt

This may be a silly question, but it's starting to getting on my nerves.

I develop with the regular ADT in eclipse, and use my Motorola Atrix 2 MB865 in 4.0.4 to test.

I have all due drivers, and eclipse recognizes the phone perfectly, and most of the times works as it should. But lately when I hit "Run" in eclipse, it shows in the bottom right of eclipse "Launching app ..." and it says 100%, but it never opens it.

Looking at the console shows

```
[2013-07-24 00:10:37 - Moveo_Android] ------------------------------
[2013-07-24 00:10:37 - Moveo_Android] Android Launch!
[2013-07-24 00:10:37 - Moveo_Android] adb is running normally.
[2013-07-24 00:10:37 - Moveo_Android] Performing co.aktio.moveo.android.SplashActivity activity launch
[2013-07-24 00:10:42 - Moveo_Android] Uploading Moveo_Android.apk onto device 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
[2013-07-24 00:10:43 - Moveo_Android] Installing Moveo_Android.apk...
[2013-07-24 00:11:06 - Moveo_Android] Success!
[2013-07-24 00:11:08 - Moveo_Android] Starting activity co.aktio.moveo.android.SplashActivity on device XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

But problem is PHONE NEVER START THE ACTIVITY!!!

So I have to dig in the menu for the app, and open it from there.

Sometimes I have to hit "Run" 3 or 4 times in a row to make it start.

Just to be clear. Eclipse DOES recognize my phone, installs the app perfectly, and does the Logcat as it should, what bothers me is that app won't start when I hit "Run" from eclipse, or at least not in 80% of the times.

May be something in settings or some file I messed up?

Comment: In your run configuration dialog screen,Ist in android tab choose launch default activity for launch action and next choose common tab in this choose Run check box and run your application it may work.

Comment: Have you tried kill-server and start-server?

Comment: @Deen the checkbox was unchecked, but still not working. Tried already 4 more times, It just worked first one.

Comment: @TarunVarshney And how exactly do I do that?

Comment: Try after uninstall your application and restart your device and run it for the same Keep your Run check box checked.

Comment: After all, restarting PC + restarting Phone + "Run" checkbox in "Commons" tab as @Deen suggested made the work. Debugging is working perfectly now.

Comment: if you think it work please upvote the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your run configuration dialog screen,Ist in android tab choose launch default activity for launch action and next choose common tab in this choose Run check box and run your application

still not working Try it after uninstall your application and restart your device and run it for the same Keep your Run check box checked It may work.

Answer (score 0):

Goto your cmd line and type,

```
adb kill-server
```

after that start your server by

```
 adb start-server
```